# How to predict masked word in a sentence in BERT-base from Tensorflow checkpoint (ckpt) files?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, predict, bert-language-model

I have BERT-base model checkpoints which I trained from scratch in Tensorflow. How can I use those checkpoints to predict masked word in a given sentence?

Like, let say sentence is,
"[CLS] abc pqr [MASK] xyz [SEP]"
And I want to predict word at [MASK] position.

How can I do it?
I searched a lot online but everyone is using BERT for their task specific classification tasks.
Not using BERT to predict masked word.

Please help me in solving this prediction problem.

I created data using `create_pretraining_data.py` & trained model from scratch using `run_pretraining.py` from official BERT repo (https://github.com/google-research/bert)

I have searched in issues in official bert repo. But didn't found any solution.

Also looked at code in that repo. They're using Estimator which they are training not using from checkpoints weights.

Didn't found any way to use way to use Tensorflow checkpoints of BERT-base model (trained from scratch) to predict word masked token (i.e. [MASK]).

Answer (score 0):

Do you definitely need to start from a TF checkpoint? If you can use one of the pretrained models used in the [pytorch-transformers](https://huggingface.co/pytorch-transformers/) library, I wrote a library for doing exactly this: [FitBERT](https://pypi.org/project/fitbert/).

If you have to start with a TF checkpoint, there are scripts for converting from a TF checkpoint to something pytorch-transformers can use, [link](https://huggingface.co/pytorch-transformers/converting_tensorflow_models.html#bert), and after converting you should be able to use FitBERT, or you can just see what we're doing in the code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I need to use those checkpoints. I trained my own BERT from scratch for Hindi language with my own vocab. I am aware that BERT is also for multilingual. But it does piecewise tokenization but I want to mask whole word (there is also research for whole word masking (WWM) but its only for English).

Comment: Did you look at the link and FitBERT? The script should cover the check point, then you can use FitBERT to predict the masked token.

Comment: Yes. I looked at it. I got the `.pth` file from BERT checkpoints. Thank you for that. BTW, is your library `FitBERT` available in conda? I tried to install by `pip3 install fitbert` but it gave me this error `ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.`

Comment: It's been tested on python3.6 and 3.7 on Ubuntu and Mac. Are you on Windows?

Comment: Ohh, no I am using Ubuntu but my python version is 3.5.x

Comment: That `.pth` file is just weights. Not the model architecture. But for `model.eval()` I will need model architecture. Using that `from_pretrained` method from `pytorch-transformers` gives English BERT architecture which have different Embedding size (as vocab size is different). Can you please help me with this?